# How to upload file bigger than 8M in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $new_name = rand() . '.' . $file->getclientOriginalExtension();
    $filesize = $request->file('file')->getSize();
    $file->move(public_path('videos'), $new_name);
    $id = Auth::user()->id;
    $datasave = new home_contents();
    $datasave->img = $new_name;
    $datasave->created_id = $id;
    $datasave->updated_id = $id;
    $datasave->save();
}
```

So please share me how fix it . 
Best regard, 
Lab

Comment: Welcome! Please can you share the error you're getting. There are potentially a few different reasons why you wouldn't be able to upload a file that is more than 8MB and there isn't anything in the code you've provided that would suggest what that reason is.

Comment: fyi, I removed the tags `javascript` and `phpmyadmin`, they seemed unrelated

Comment: The file size is limited only by a web server. Check your php.ini upload_max_filesize setting.

Comment: For my code it is working fine only file under 8M only , If i try to upload file bigger than 8M it is not work .

Comment: What kind of error did you get? Have you try to increase the file size in validation like ``'file' => 'required|file|size:10000'``

Comment: @FaristaLatuconsina Yes i have already validation on file  but I still can be upload file under 8M if I upload file bigger than 8M my laravel code can get file size of that file

Comment: What error are you getting i.e. what is telling you that you can't upload a file of more than 8MB? Is it a javascript error in your console, is it a PHP error, is it a validation error? Please can you take a screenshot of what the error is and show us.

Comment: @Rwd here my code    
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'file' => 'max:10240', 
        ]);
      $file = $request->file('file');
      $new_name = rand() . '.' .$file->getclientOriginalExtension();
      $filesize=$request->file('file')->getSize();
      $file->move(public_path('videos'), $new_name);
      return "file moved";

    }
For error it is not show when my file upload bigger than 8M ,

Comment: Wait, why is that different to the code you have in your question? Also, have you checked your browser console, network tab, or Laravel log to confirm you're not getting an error? Again, with the information you've provided there isn't anything to suggest what the issue is. Are you using a javascript library to upload the file or just a standard form? Have you tried uploading a different file that is between 8-10MB?

Comment: Oh i just clear some of code and I'm only try to focus on move file only. yes i'm not getting error . And i didn't use javascript library  I'm use only standard form. yes i have tried to upload with different file size already.  but when i'm tried to get the big file from folder it is fine . except upload file

Answer (score 1):

Try to increase the following config in your  php.ini, for example:

```
post_max_size = 12M
upload_max_filesize = 10M
```

The `post_max_size` is the maximum size for all post body data while the `upload_max_filesize` is a maximum size for files that exist in the post request, which makes sense having different values.

Comment: Yes bro i'm already changed in php.ini and already restart my server but it still the same, Do you have any idea more ?

Comment: @lab Use `phpinfo()` in a php file on your server to make sure the changes you made have been applied. Did you edit the correct php.ini?

Comment: Yes when i'm tried to dd($filesize); i'm got the message false , it is not return value of file size bro ,Do you have any idea ?

Comment: @Mohmmed Yassine , Yes I did to change the value in php.ini post_max_size = 12M
upload_max_filesize = 10M , and i'm got the message false when dd(filesize) (Only for file that have size bigger than 8M), it is not return value of file size bro

Comment: @ Mohammed Yassine CHABLI and i used try with create my own function in php for use , but the result is the same , I can upload file under 8M ,It is the same i use function of laravel 7.x

Comment: If you are using `nginx` as your Webserver, there are configurations that will affect file upload size limit as well. So, you need to let us know the **Webserver** that you are using and the **error message** you got.

Comment: @kenfai and all I'm thank you so much for your quickly replied and share to me. For now I found the solution. I  just edit file .htaccess and add the code
php_value upload_max_filesize 540M
php_value post_max_size 565M
php_value max.excution_time 300
Then it work fine